How to create Pyspark code that will create a white space in Databricks Notebook cell
I would like help with Python(PySpark) that will continually create a white space or simply  move the cursor in a Databricks notebook cell.
For example, in the image I have manually moved the cursor across, is there a way I can write code to automate the moving of the cursor in the notebook cell.


If you can clarify the exact use case or purpose behind moving the cursor, I might help.
Is your aim to avoid session timeouts?

Hi @Mario, thanks for getting in touch. Yes, it is to avoid session timeouts. I should have mentioned that in the first place. Thanks

Hang on@Mario, its not session timeouts as you might think. I know how to set idle timeout if that is work you're thinking. I'm thinking more about a means to keep my screen or another application from timing out.

I would ideally like to get this funtionality with almost any application, I just it would be easier to do so with Databricks as I work with databricks all the time.

I might be more accurate to state that I would like to use databricks to activate a key stroke

To the best of my knowledge, Python code does not have native access to the cursor position within a notebook cell in a Databricks notebook, as that is typically managed by the notebook's frontend interface (such as the JavaScript running in the web browser). Therefore, it is not possible to directly control cursor movement within a Databricks notebook cell using Python or PySpark code alone.
However, there are alternative approaches if the goal is to create activity or simulate "keep-alive" behavior within the notebook. you can use time.sleep() in a loop to keep a cell-active.
import time

# Keep cell active for a specific period
for I in range(3600*2):                  # 2 hours but you can adjust the range as needed for longer or shorter activity
    print(f"Iteration {i+1}", end="\r")  # This will update the line repeatedly
    time.sleep(1)                        # Sleep for 1 second, adjust as needed

You might also consider adjusting the cluster timeout settings or using Databricks REST API to programmatically check and restart clusters if needed.
